# Request body as ReadableStream

Tags: javascript

Request `body` [should accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) `ReadableStream` but if I do this:

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org/get')
    .then(resp => {
        return new Request('https://example.com', {
           method: 'POST',
           body: resp.body
        })      
    })
    .then(req => req.text())
    .then(alert)
```

when I read request body getting text `[object ReadableStream]`. [Try this example.](https://jsfiddle.net/qLe8gbmu/4/)

How to stream data from the response to the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this issue is fixed, then response body can be streamed:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=688906

Comment: Would you believe that the current release (v104) of Chromium still doesn't support this?!? v105 should though according to comments on that bug report. According to MDN, nobody but Deno 1.7 supports it today: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request#browser_compatibility (search "Send ReadableStream in request body")